# Function if else statements read from different data sets

Tags: r

I am very new to R. I am trying to get my function to take output a table with the columns I designate in my function when a user inputs a date (mm/dd/yy) and season (yyyy/yy). I am confused as to how to set up my initial data frame.

So there are 3 seasons I am pulling from (3 urls). My IF statement should be reading into one df (called it dfmess, cuz its a mess). How would I do this, hopefully that makes sense and someone can help me.  I would be very grateful if someone can sort out this mess for me...

```
    Season_2015_16 <- read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1516/E0.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    Season_2014_15 <- read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1415/E0.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    Season_2013_14 <- read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1314/E0.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    **dfmess <- read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1516/E0.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    dfmess <- read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1415/E0.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    dfmess <- read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1314/E0.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)**

    EPL_Standings <- function(Standingdate, season){
      Standingdate <- as.Date(Standingdate, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
      Standingdate <- as.Date("08/30/15", format = "%m/%d/%y")
      if (season == "2015/16"){

        read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1516/E0.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) -> dfmess

      } else if (season == "2014/15") {
        read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1415/E0.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) -> dfmess

      } else if (season == "2013/14"){
        read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1314/E0.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) -> dfmess

      }

    dfmess[dfmess$Date <= Standingdate, 2:6]
  #Team Record


  ddply(dfmess, 
        .(HomeTeam)
        , summarize
        , win = sum(FTR == "H")
        , Loss = sum(FTR == "A")
        , Draws = sum(FTR == "D")
  ) -> homewins1    #Homerecord
  ddply(dfmess, 
        .(AwayTeam)
        , summarize
        , win = sum(FTR == "A")
        , Loss = sum(FTR == "H")
        , Draws = sum(FTR == "D")
  ) -> awaywins1  #Awayrecord

  merge(homewins1, awaywins1, by.x = "HomeTeam", by.y = "AwayTeam", all = TRUE) -> homeawayrec

  #homeawayrec
  (homeawayrec$win.x + homeawayrec$win.y) -> homeawayrec$totalwins #adds away and home wins together, then puts on table. renamed column later
  (homeawayrec$Loss.x + homeawayrec$Loss.y) -> homeawayrec$Total.Losses #same as above, but Losses. Named consistently with what I changed too after I changed above column. 
  (homeawayrec$Draws.x + homeawayrec$Draws.y) -> homeawayrec$Total.Draws #same as above, but with Draws. 
  #names(homeawayrec) <- c("Teams","Home.Wins", "Home.Losses", "Home.Draws", "Away.Wins", "Away.Losses", "Away.Draws", "Total.Wins") #Name all columns. make sure name right thing. 

  #homeawayrec[, c("Teams", "Total.Wins", "Total.Draws", "Total.Losses")] -> WDL

  #Need to make home and away record, should be easy. 

  #homewins1 #homerecord
  #awaywins1 #awayrecord

  #Matches Played

  (homeawayrec$totalwins + homeawayrec$Total.Draws + homeawayrec$Total.Losses) -> homeawayrec$MatchesPlayed
  #homeawayrec

  #homeawayrec[, c("Teams", "MatchesPlayed")] -> Matches.Played
  #Matches.Played #number of matches played
  #POINTS (need to make it per match)

  #ddply(dfmess, 
  # .(HomeTeam)                    #DDPLY Points was eliminated because multiplying the wins by 3 and draws by 1 was easier. 
  #  , summarize
  #   , win = 3*(sum(FTR == "H"))
  #    , Loss = 0*(sum(FTR == "A"))
  #     , Draws = 1*(sum(FTR == "D"))
  #) -> HomePoints   #team points at home

  #ddply(dfmess, 
  #     .(AwayTeam)
  #    , summarize
  #   , win = 3*(sum(FTR == "A"))
  #  , Loss = 0*(sum(FTR == "H"))
  #      , Draws = 1*(sum(FTR == "D"))
  #) -> AwayPoints   #team points on road

  #merge(HomePoints, AwayPoints, by.x = "HomeTeam", by.y = "AwayTeam", all = TRUE) -> Pointshomeaway

  #(HomePoints$win +HomePoints$Draws + AwayPoints$win + AwayPoints$Draws) -> Pointshomeaway$TotalPoints

  #names(Pointshomeaway) <- c("Teams", "HomeWinPoints", "HomeLossPoints", "HomeDrawPoints", "AwayWinPoints", "AwayLossPoints", "AwayDrawPoints", "TotalPoints")

  #Pointshomeaway[, c("Teams", "TotalPoints")] -> Points.standings #table with just total points, total points standings. 
  #homeawayrec
  (3*(homeawayrec$totalwins)+(1*(homeawayrec$Total.Draws))) -> homeawayrec$Points

  #points per match and point percentage %
  #homeawayrec
  (3*(homeawayrec$totalwins)+(1*(homeawayrec$Total.Draws)))/(homeawayrec$MatchesPlayed) -> homeawayrec$PPM

  #homeawayrec[, c("Teams", "PointsPerMatch")] -> PointsPer.Standings #standings with teams and points per match. 

  #Point Percentage
  (homeawayrec$Points)/(3*(homeawayrec$MatchesPlayed)) -> homeawayrec$PtPct
  #homeawayrec
  #Goals Scored

  ddply(dfmess,                           #THIS WORKED, make sure HomeTeam and FTHG/AwayTeam and FTAG match up. Goals allowed will be the inverse for each. 
        .(HomeTeam)
        , summarize
        , goalsscored1 = sum(FTHG)
  ) -> Homegoalmade1
  ddply(dfmess, 
        .(AwayTeam)
        , summarize
        , goalsscored1 = sum(FTAG)
  ) -> Awaygoalsmade1

  merge(Homegoalmade1, Awaygoalsmade1, by.x = "HomeTeam", by.y = "AwayTeam", all = TRUE) -> goalsmade1 #merged home/away goalsmmade1 THIS WORKED
  (goalsmade1$goalsscored1.x + goalsmade1$goalsscored1.y) -> goalsmade1$allgoalsmade1 #total goalsmade

  #goalsmade1

  goalsmade1[, c("HomeTeam", "allgoalsmade1")] -> GS

  merge(homeawayrec, GS, by.x = "HomeTeam", by.y = "HomeTeam", all = TRUE) -> homeawayrec1
  #homeawayrec
  #homeawayrec1

  #Goals Scored Per Match
  ((homeawayrec1$allgoalsmade1)/(homeawayrec1$MatchesPlayed)) -> homeawayrec1$GSM
  #homeawayrec1

  #Goals Allowed
  ddply(dfmess,                           #THIS WORKED, make sure HomeTeam and FTAG/AwayTeam and FTHG match up. Goals scored will be the inverse for each. 
        .(HomeTeam)
        , summarize
        , goalsscored1 = sum(FTAG)
  ) -> Homegoalallowed1
  ddply(dfmess, 
        .(AwayTeam)
        , summarize
        , goalsscored1 = sum(FTHG)
  ) -> Awaygoalsallowed1

  merge(Homegoalallowed1, Awaygoalsallowed1, by.x = "HomeTeam", by.y = "AwayTeam", all = TRUE) -> goalsallowed1

  (goalsallowed1$goalsscored1.x + goalsallowed1$goalsscored1.y) -> goalsallowed1$GA

  #goalsallowed1

  goalsallowed1[, c("HomeTeam", "allgoalsallowed1")] -> GoalsAllowedall

  merge(homeawayrec1, goalsallowed1, by.x = "HomeTeam", by.y = "HomeTeam", all = TRUE) -> homeawayrec2

  #Goals Allowed Per Match

  ((homeawayrec2$GA)/homeawayrec2$MatchesPlayed) -> homeawayrec2$GAM
  names(homeawayrec2)
  #putting columns in correct order
  #if I rename columns the function gets confused and won't work?
  homeawayrec2[, c(1, 8, 10, 9, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 6, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 19, 20)]
  #Last 10 matches played
  ((tail(homeawayrec2$totalwins, n=10)) (tail(homeawayrec2$Total.Draws, n=10)) (tail(homeawayrec2$Total.Losses, n=10)))
  tail(homeawayrec2[, c("totalwins", "Total.Draws", "Total.Losses")], n=10)
  homeawayrec2
  print(homeawayrec2)
  return(dfmess)
}
      ((homeawayrec2$GA)/homeawayrec2$MatchesPlayed) -> homeawayrec2$GAM
      names(homeawayrec2)
      homeawayrec2[, c(1, 8, 10, 9, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 6, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 19, 20)]
      print(homeawayrec2)
      return(dfmess)
    }
    A <- EPL_Standings("09/26/14", "2013/14") #example numbers, placeholders. 
    head(A)
```

Comment: Your `if` statements look fine, but you probably want to assign the `read.csv` inside the `if`s to an object, `dfmess <- read.csv(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I made that change, but I still get this Error: Error in `[.data.frame`(goalsallowed1, , c("HomeTeam", "allgoalsallowed1")) : 
  undefined columns selected

I googled it and did not get any explanations. I also tried help on R, but don't understand. Do you know the issue. How could I define columns?

Comment: @UKcats82 it means that either "HomeTeam" or "allgoalsallowed1" is not a valid column name in the "goalsallowed" data frame. Check for typos. I'd be glad to help out some more, but yesterday I poured a glass of water on my computer, so I don't currently have access to R.

Comment: Also it would be very helpful if you could explain what is wrong with your output, or if you could post any errors and warnings you get. Your code isn't that short and it will make it easier to find issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start. In general, it is best to keep similar data in the same table.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)

data =
  data_frame(start_season = c(2013, 2014, 2015)) %>%
  mutate(url =
           (start_season - 2000) %>%
           paste0(., . + 1) %>%
           sprintf("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/%s/E0.csv", . ) ) %>%
  group_by(start_season) %>%
  do(read.csv(.$url)) %>%
  mutate(Date = dmy(Date) %>% as.Date) %>%
  arrange(Date)

cutoffs =
  data %>%
  group_by(start_season) %>%
  summarize(start_date = first(Date))

EPL_Standings = function(specific_date) {

  specific_date = mdy(specific_date) %>% as.Date

  this_season_so_far = 
    cutoffs %>%
    filter(specific_date > start_date) %>%
    last %>%
    left_join(data) %>%
    filter(Date <= specific_date)

  # some sort of processing here
}
```

Comment: I tried that but for some reason it just gives me a + ...so maybe my processing is just garbage. Its my first function (assignment for class). Never have had any kind of programming experience before.

Comment: If you could tell me whether or not my processing is good/bad I would appreciate it, you don't have to tell me what is wrong because I understand that is asking a lot (unless you want to). I would just like to know if what I was doing seemed correct.

Comment: Also, that doesn't seem to work at all. Maybe I am just terrible at this, but even with processing that should work it throws a lot of errors.

Comment: @UKcats82 did you forget the closing brace at the end of the `EPL_Standings` function?

Comment: Made a small change to get this season so far. Dunno if that helps

Comment: @ssdecontrol2 I did not, just didn't copy it when asking the question. I apologize.